# How to get the PIDs of the child processes?

Tags: c, windows, pid

Is there a way, to get the PIDs of the child processes? I mean, if i open a cmd prompt using CreateProcess, i know its PID because i can get it from the returned ProcessInformation structure. But is it possible to get the PIDs of the processes too, which were opened from this command prompt?

Thanks!

Comment: So you actually do not want the PIDs from a child but from the **grand**-children.

Comment: @alk: Yes, exactaly that is what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function passing the `TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS` value, then call the [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method , and finally you must iterate over the collection returned and compare the value of the [`th32ParentProcessID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field against the PID of the cmd.exe. Another option is use the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Class using the `ParentProcessId` property to filter the results.

Comment: This appraoch sure works for statistical purposes. Using the PIDs returned for any sort of IPC is unsecure, as PIDs come and go and probably having been reused.

Answer (score 0):

Create a job using [CreateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use [SetInformationJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to associate the job with an I/O completion port; see [JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.  Create the process with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and use [AssignProcessToJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make the new process part of the job.

Keep in mind that sometimes the new grandchild process will have exited already by the time you see the process ID, and that process can be reused.  If you use [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the grandchild process, make sure you process errors properly, and if you do open a handle successfully make sure you call [IsProcessInJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to verify that the handle is indeed pointing to one of the grandchild processes.

Since processes cannot be nested prior to Windows 8/2012, you might need to use the `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag when creating the child process.

Comment: Another approach would be to write some kernel-mode code using PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine to monitor all process creation in real time.  This is more trouble in Vista and later because of the driver signing requirements, but for XP it might be a useful alternative.